# Atomic Structure of Liquids!

Tags: atomic-physics

Reframe: Liquids have a molecular arrangement less dense than that of solids. The liquid molecules are not stuck to each other like those of the solids. So my question is what lies in these spaces between two molecules which allows the liquid to look continuous and not something with regular spaces(like a sponge has holes).

Comment: What do you mean "what lies in between"? Nothing.

Comment: You have to be careful with "and have a molecular structure not as rigidly packed as solids". There are plenty of solids that have lower density than liquids and even ice can float on water, which is extremely important for the climate of earth-like planets. Having said that, there are no simple answers about the structure of liquids. There are liquids with little internal structure and then there are extremely well ordered liquids (think liquid crystals!). The same substance can phase change from one state to another over a tiny temperature and density range. In other words: it's complicated!

Answer (score 0):

Interaction between neutral atoms/molecules is described by such a potential that the force is that of repulsion at smaller distances and that of attraction at greater distances. The repulsion is Pauli repulsion, so it is (parts of) electronic orbitals that are between atoms/molecules. With higher temperature, the oscillatory energy is higher, and the atoms are "higher" in the potential well, that typically means that the mean distance is greater (but water is one of the exceptions, and liquid water is denser than ice).